# Laravel Model protected $dateFormat - How to remove seconds?

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, timestamp, laravel-5.1

Platform: Laravel 5.1

Database: MySQL

I'm also using Fractal Transformers for transforming my returned data to JSON objects.

After putting this `protected $dateFormat = 'Y-m-d H:i';` in my Model(note the missing `:s`) Carbon is throwing errors:

```
exception 'InvalidArgumentException' with message 'Trailing data' in C:\project1\vendor\nesbot\carbon\src\Carbon\Carbon.php:425
```

According to the documentation this should work: https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators

I've tried the following:

- Change my MySQL table structure from `TIMESTAMP` to `DATETIME`- no change
- Changing the returned value with `substr($time, 0, -3)` - got errors
- Asking in Gitter for help, got this:

> I might be using a different Persistence that doesn't use the MySQL format
>
> *What does this mean?*

How do I make sure `Carbon::now()` or MySQL is creating timestamps without seconds?

OR

How do I return only `Y-m-d H:i`?

Comment: Did you find an answer to this?

Answer (score 2):

With the help of **Accessor & mutators** you can format the timestamp as you would like to.

Here's an example of created_at timestamp:

```
`public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
 { 
      return $this->asDateTime($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i'); 
 }`
```

Here's an example of updated_at timestamp with a little bit different format:

```
`public function getUpdatedAtAttribute($value)
 {
     return $this->asDateTime($value)->format('d/m/Y - H:i');
 }`
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following

Place the following code on your model

```
 protected $casts = ['date_time'=>'date'];
```

For carbon use the following

```
 Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d H:i');
```

Comment: No joy. Had to use the following but now it won't include `timezone_type` and and `timezone`:
`public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value){ return $this->asDateTime($value)->format('Y-m-d H:i'); } `